# Do exist infinitely many unitary transformations between two real vectors?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, unitary-matrices

Are there infinitely many unitary transformations to satisfy the relation $U\left| b \right\rangle  = \left| a \right\rangle $ (where $UU^{\dagger} = U^{\dagger}U=1$) between two arbitrary, normalized *real* vectors? For having infinitely many unitary transformations, I think the two vectors must have same norms and this is a crucial condition. Am I right?

Comment: $Ub=a$ implies $b,a$ have the same norm, so that is a necessary condition. Conversely if they have the same norm, we can normalize them to be unit vectors, then we can extend $\{b\},\{a\}$ to ordered orthonormal bases $\{b_1,\cdots,b_n\}$, $\{a_1,\cdots,a_n\}$ and finally define $U$ by $Ub_i=a_i$ (extended linearly), which is a unitary transformation. If $n>1$, there are infinitely many ways to do this, indeed for any given choice of bases we can multiply the vectors other than $b,a$ themselves by phasors, of which there are infinitely many.

Comment: @runway44, Thank you very much. A clear explanation!

Comment: Also there is no automatic notion of which vectors in an inner product space are "real" and which are not - that requires the space to have additional structure, called a "real structure," or an antilinear involution (which exists if you have chosen coordinates, for instance - you take the complex conjugate of coordinates). Even given a real structure, the vectors being real or not isn't relevant.

Comment: @runway44, your comments were really helpful for me. Now, I understand better. Thanks again.